# How to put CheckBox and button on same line in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Is possible to place the checkbox and button on the same line in a vertical Linear Layout?

I made the button and checkbox programmatically with this code:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
        btn.setTextSize(24);
        btn.append(rs1.getString(0));
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        //ll = Linear Layout (vertical)
        ll.addView(checkBox);
        ll.addView(btn);
```

In this case the checbox is over the button

Someone can help me?

EDIT:
[Image that explain what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwq9o.png)

Comment: Maybe `ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);` will help you.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please elaborate or add image of your desired layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a higher hierarchy for your views. Like adding your both views in a horizontal `LinearLayout` and then add the new layout to your root layout. Your code would look like this:

```
LinearLayout myLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
myLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
btn.setTextSize(24);
btn.append(rs1.getString(0));
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
myLinearLayout.addView(checkBox);
myLinearLayout.addView(btn);
ll.addView(myLinearLayout);
```